# Showing that the mapping det either homogenous nor additive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently preparing myself for an exam in Mathematics. I got stuck on this task:

*Show in the space of real 2 × 2 matrices that the mapping det is neither homogeneous
nor additive, so in particular it is not linear.*

Could anybody please explain to me, how to handle it? I would be very grateful for any advices!

Comment: Do you know what to be homogeneous and additive mean? If yes, just find examples of matrices to prove that $\det$ doesn’t satisfy those properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make an educated guess with the term "homogeneous," but you're being asked to show that it is *not* the case that
$$\det(cA) = c \det(A)\quad \text{for all}\ A \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}\ \text{and}\ c \in \mathbb R,$$
and
$$\det(A + B) = \det(A) + \det(B) \quad \text{for all}\ A, B \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}.$$

Were these two equations to hold, then $\det : \mathbb R^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb R$ would be an example of a linear map. So my suggestion is to play around with some examples to see why the equations don't always hold.